# How can I minify duplicated css proprieties code between css classes?

Tags: css, less

I have a less code which will compile to css code, now all is fine , but I need to minify my css code because some classes they have the same css proprieties. Is there any way to gather theme to one function and call it after inside the class or some things like that?

Here is my code :

```
    // first css code 
    .relative-password-div-create {
                position: relative;

                .icon-eye-password-create {
                    width: 1.25em;
                    height: 0.75em;
                    position: relative;
                    display: inline-block;
                    --background: @vejmag_white-color;
                    --color: currentColor;

                    div {
                        overflow: hidden;
                        height: 50%;
                        position: relative;
                        margin-bottom: -1px;

                        &:before {
                            content: '';
                            background: currentColor;
                            position: absolute;
                            left: 0;
                            right: 0;
                            height: 300%;
                            border-radius: 100%;
                        }

                        &:last-child {
                            &:before {
                                bottom: 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    &:before {
                        content: '';
                        position: absolute;
                        top: 50%;
                        left: 50%;
                        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                        width: 0.35em;
                        height: 0.35em;
                        background: var(--color);
                        border: 0.1em solid var(--background);
                        border-radius: 100%;
                        z-index: 1;
                    }

                    &:after {
                        content: '';
                        position: absolute;
                        top: -0.15em;
                        left: calc(33.333% - 0.15em);
                        transform: rotate(45deg) scaleX(0);
                        transform-origin: left center;
                        width: 90%;
                        height: 0.1em;
                        background: var(--color);
                        border-top: 0.1em solid var(--background);
                        z-index: 2;
                        transition: transform 0.25s;
                    }

                }

                .icon-eye-password-create.slash {
                    &:after {
                        transform: rotate(45deg) scaleX(1);
                        left: 4px;
                    }
                }

                div#togglePasswordCreate {
                    position: absolute;
                    z-index: 4;
                    right: 0em;
                    top: 1em;
                }

            }
            

             //same css code as first class above

            .relative-password-div-create-confirm {
                position: relative;

                .icon-eye-password-create-confirm {
                    width: 1.25em;
                    height: 0.75em;
                    position: relative;
                    display: inline-block;
                    --background: @vejmag_white-color;
                    --color: currentColor;

                    div {
                        overflow: hidden;
                        height: 50%;
                        position: relative;
                        margin-bottom: -1px;

                        &:before {
                            content: '';
                            background: currentColor;
                            position: absolute;
                            left: 0;
                            right: 0;
                            height: 300%;
                            border-radius: 100%;
                        }

                        &:last-child {
                            &:before {
                                bottom: 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    &:before {
                        content: '';
                        position: absolute;
                        top: 50%;
                        left: 50%;
                        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                        width: 0.35em;
                        height: 0.35em;
                        background: var(--color);
                        border: 0.1em solid var(--background);
                        border-radius: 100%;
                        z-index: 1;
                    }

                    &:after {
                        content: '';
                        position: absolute;
                        top: -0.15em;
                        left: calc(33.333% - 0.15em);
                        transform: rotate(45deg) scaleX(0);
                        transform-origin: left center;
                        width: 90%;
                        height: 0.1em;
                        background: var(--color);
                        border-top: 0.1em solid var(--background);
                        z-index: 2;
                        transition: transform 0.25s;
                    }
                }

                .icon-eye-password-create-confirm.slash {
                    &:after {
                        transform: rotate(45deg) scaleX(1);
                        left: 4px;
                    }
                }

                div#togglePasswordCreateConfirm {
                    position: absolute;
                    z-index: 4;
                    right: 0em;
                    top: 1em;
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [mixins](https://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature) which are actually just classes which you can call them as functions. Here is an example from the documentation:

```
.my-mixin {
  color: black;
}

/* This class won't be included in the
 * final css because it has parantheses in the name */
.my-other-mixin() {
  background: white;
}

.class {
  .my-mixin();
  .my-other-mixin();
}
```

outputed css:

```css
.my-mixin {
  color: black;
}

.class {
  color: black;
  background: white;
}
```